# Any way to synchronize all premise databases in one go through 'Sql Azure Sync Group'?

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, data-synchronization, azure-data-sync

I have two on premise databases in my `synchronization group in sql azure`. When I synchronize the group manually,  I see that only one of the premise database gets all the updated data and the other one does not.

I have to synchronize a second time to get the updated data to the other premise database.

I can imagine why this is happening, but there must be some way to synchronize both of them in one go.

Please tell me any possible solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, you need at least two syncs to get data convergence on both on-premise databases.

The sync process syncs each member database in a serial manner. Member databases synched earlier will not incorporate the changes that were synched from other member databases that were synched after it. For member databases to be fully synchronized with each other, you need to perform at least two passes across the sync group.